# SELECT min and max value from a table in sql server increases CPU usages

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

If I want to select min and max values from a table I can use this:

```
SELECT CVC.CurrencyVSCurrencyId,MAX(SP.High) High,MIN(SP.Low) Low,CVC.Title FROM YearHighLow  SP  
 INNER JOIN CurrencyVSCurrency CVC ON SP.Currency=CVC.Title  
 WHERE CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Time,101) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()),101) AS DATETIME) AND CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Time,101) AS DATETIME)  
 GROUP BY  CVC.CurrencyVSCurrencyId,CVC.Title
```

When this query executed, CPU usage reach to 100%.
YearHighLow table contain only 13 rows & CurrencyVSCurrency table contains 153 rows only.

How can I solve this problem with minimum queries?

Comment: Be happy that your CPU has something to do. How long is the query running?

Comment: When I manully execute query in sql server it will take 0.1 ms But When I see from profiler then Duration="1235253".

Comment: Then the problem seems not to be the query but the way you execute it in ASP.NET. Show some code.

Comment: execute procedure to get data table using sqlDataadapter.

Comment: Yes, show that code. Does it take so long on IIS or in your development-environment?